# Swift 3 CMMotionManager startGyroUpdates not working

Tags: swift, handler, core-motion

I have got the following code from Objective-C, it works great.

```
_motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
_motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 1.0/60.0;

[_motionManager startGyroUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMGyroData *gyroData, NSError *error)
{

        xAcceleration = gyroData.rotationRate.x;
        yAcceleration = gyroData.rotationRate.y;

    [self acceleratorUpdates];

}];
```

And i tried to convert it to Swift 3 but it doesn't work, it gives all kinds off errors. So far i got this code.

```
let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

    motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 1.0 / 60.0


    motionManager.startGyroUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!, withHandler: {(gyroData: CMGyroData, error: Error)
        var xAcceleration = gyroData.rotationRate.x
        var yAcceleration = gyroData.rotationRate.y

        print("xAcceleration: ", xAcceleration, "yAcceleration: ", yAcceleration)
    })
```

I think I'm missing something in the withHandler part. The documentation said this: -> Void in after the handler but that didn't help. All the codes from the web are Swift 2.

Comment: It worked after making `motionManager` as an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

try this in a method of your class:

```
// data members:
private var gyroPresent = false
private var manager : CMMotionManager?
```

..

```
self.manager = CMMotionManager()
guard self.manager != nil else {
    // never here.. but... to be sure.
    print("no CMMotionManager")
    return
}

self.gyroPresent = self.manager!.isGyroAvailable
guard self.gyroPresent else {
    print("no GyroScope")
    return
}

self.manager!.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.1

// remember to stop it.. with:      self.manager?.stopGyroUpdates()
self.manager!.startGyroUpdates(to: OperationQueue.main) { (data: CMGyroData?, error: Error?) in
    if let  info = data?.rotationRate{
            print("\(info.x)  \(info.z)  \(info.z) ")
        }
    }

...
```

tested on Xcode 8.2.1/swift 3.x and device iOS 10.2.1 (14D27)

PS
be sure to use capture list to prevent retain cycles if using self:

```
{ [unowned self] in
   ...
}
```